# Php autoloader for css / js only works on one page

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to autoload all css/js files with a glob function. This is currently working but only on one page. if I try to call the function on a other page it does include them but the files seems to be empty if I inspect them in my browser.
I have litterly no clue where to look for and what is wrong.

**css load function:**

```
public function loadCss(){
    $folder = glob('/public/assets/css/*.{css}', GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach ($folder as $filename) {
        echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='$filename'>\n";
    }
}
```

**index.php:**

```
   require_once './app/core/autoload.php';
$al = new autoload();
$al->addDirectories(
    array(
        'app/core',
        'app/mvc',
        'app/router',
        'app/lib',
        'app/models',
    ));
$al->register();

try{
    $mvc  = new mvc\mvc();
    $mvc->start();
    echo $mvc->getView();

}catch(Exception $e){
    echo '<B>Error message:</B> '.$e->getMessage();
}
?>

<head>
    <?php
        $bs = new \bootstrap\bootstrap();
        $bs->loadCss();
        $bs->loadJS();
    ?>
</head>
```

If there are better ways of doing this I would like to know it :P

Answer (score 0):

The `glob` function returns filenames with no path. If your CSS files are stored in `/assets/css` relative to the document root (e.g. `http://localhost/assets/css/main.css`), then your link tags will only work if the page is also in the same directory (e.g. `http://localhost/assets/css/test.php`).

Try adding the absolute path to the `href` attribute of the `link` elements.

Comment: thanks for the response, The files are loading in now but the it isn't applying the styles. my url to the file is now: php.dev./public/assets/css/custom.css which is good because if i paste that in the browser it shows the css file

Comment: If the CSS files are now loading with the page, but the styles aren't applying, that's probably a problem with the CSS itself. Btw, you can verify that they are loading in by using the network tab in the developer tools (F12 in most browsers).

Comment: I just saw the error after I posted it it says: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:, I've added type= text/css to the link but it still doesnt reconize the css

Comment: Where does this message appear? The message does imply though that the file was interpreted correctly, even if the MIME type was wrong. The MIME type header for the CSS file will most likely be set by your web server, which will probably be guessing based on the file extension. Are you sure the extension is `.css`?

Comment: The message appears in the console of the website, these are my CSS files http://prntscr.com/bi0wj2 , and this is the link for the inlcude <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='$filename'> Could the error be in my .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I load css and js files, the only requirement is that they need to have the same name as the php file. For instance, my_script.php must have a css/my_script.css and/or js/my_script.js

```
$script = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // current script
$script = explode('/', $script); // convert url to array
$script = end($script); // grab the last element

$css = str_replace('php', 'css', $script);
$js = str_replace('php', 'js', $script);

if (file_exists("css/$css")) {
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/$css'>";
}
if (file_exists("js/$js")) {
    echo "<script src='js/$js'></script>";
}
```